# PHP PDO - Insert is done, but error returned

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm using PHP PDO with MS SQL server using `sqlsrv` driver. I'm running a procedure that has to insert some data and I see that the insert is done as it's entered to the database. But I still get an error in return, the error says

```
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 8114 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to int. )
```

This is part of the stored procedure

[image: stored procedure definition]

and here is the relevant piece of code

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UsersManagement.spUsersInsert :InsertUser, :UserName, :FirstName");

$stmt->bindParam('InsertUser', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam('UserName', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam('FirstName', $_POST['first_name']);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
      echo 'OK';
} else {
      print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

You can see that I've explicitly said `PDO::PARAM_INT` where it requires an integer, so what could the error be?

Comment: check what is in $_SESSION['user_id'].

Comment: The error is what you have typed on the question. More interesting is insert is done even the error. Unfortunately, I can't say why it is being inserted, just I can say is try `intval($_SESSION['user_id'])` and you probably won't get an error.